# Determine approximative field of view through a mirror.

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

While developping a game with Unreal Engine, I'm trying to calculate what a player can see when looking at a mirror. The figure below illustrates the reflected approximative field of view that I'm trying to calculate.

A player (not represented in the figure) is looking at a mirror AB (considering the player sees all the mirror and not just only a part of it). The extensions of the extremities of its field of view are represented as the lines (AA') and (BB'). To approximate the next calculations, I want to retrieve the cone defined by A'MB'. The range of his view is set by the length MM'.

So in total as data we have:

- The length AB
- The angle $\alpha$ (defined as the angle between (the line orthogonal to (AB)), and (AA'))
- The angle $\beta$  (defined as the angle between (the line orthogonal to (AB)), and (BB'))
- The length MM'
- A'MB' is isosceles (MA' = MB')
- M is the middle of [AB]

The question is: how to calculate the length AA' and BB' ?

[image: Figure]

What I tried so far:

- Draw right-angled triangle to apply trigonometric functions (with the height of the triangles AMA' or BMB' for example) but I couldn't find any triangle that would help me solve it.
- Draw the extension of the lines (AA') and (BB') to obtain a triangle including A'MB' but I did not find any use for it.
- Ask a lot of people around me without any luck ^^

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've given way of solution to you in the chat.

> Let mark $MA'=MB'=l$. Using cosine rule one can express $AA'$ and $BB'$ in terms of $AB$, $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $l$.
> Then one can use $A'B'^2=(a\cos\alpha-b\cos\beta)^2+(AB+b\sin\beta-a\sin\alpha)^2=4(l^2-r^2)$.
> This is equation on $l$.
> After finding $l$, one can put it into expressions for $AA'$ and $BB'$.

Equation for $l$ is too hard to solve it analytically:

$$4\,r^2+\left(\sin \beta\,\left(\sqrt{l^2-\cos ^2\beta\,d^2}-\sin 
 \beta\,d\right)+\sin \alpha\,\left(-\sqrt{l^2-\cos ^2\alpha\,d^2}-
 \sin \alpha\,d\right)+2\,d\right)^2+\left(\cos \alpha\,\left(\sqrt{l
 ^2-\cos ^2\alpha\,d^2}+\sin \alpha\,d\right)-\cos \beta\,\left(
 \sqrt{l^2-\cos ^2\beta\,d^2}-\sin \beta\,d\right)\right)^2-4\,l^2=0$$

I believe (I may be wrong in it), if even analytical expression of $l$ in terms of $r=MM'$, $d=AB/2$, $\alpha$, $\beta$ exists, it will be too long to write it in a program code. As your need suggests numerical calculation I propose to solve it numerically.

Numerical procedure may be the following:

1. Write function for calculation of residue $res$ of equation as function of $l$, using formulae:

$$a=d \sin \alpha+\sqrt{l^2-d^2\cos^2\alpha}$$
$$b=-d \sin \beta+\sqrt{l^2-d^2\cos^2\beta}$$
$$l_1=a\cos\alpha-b\cos\beta$$
$$l_2=2d+b\sin\beta-a\sin\alpha$$
$$res=l_1^2+l_2^2+4r^2-4l^2$$

2. Make search of $l$ that makes $res$ zero. You can start with $l=d$ and increase with rough steps until residue becomes negative. Then you can use half division, till get necessary precision.
3. Put found $l$ value into $a$ and $b$ expressions.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I didn't think of the cosine rule. I'm glad to understand how it could be solved analytically even though it's complicated (my curiosity is satisfied!).
I'll go with the numeric approach you suggested.